# Python Compare distribution: SciPy ks_2samp p-value always 0.0

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, statistics, kolmogorov-smirnov

I am trying to compare two distributions and see if they are similar or different. I tried using the ks_2samp from the python scipy package. Here is my code,

```
from scipy.stats import truncnorm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

def get_truncated_normal(mean=0, sd=1, low=0, upp=10):
    return truncnorm(low - mean) / sd, (upp - mean) / sd, loc=mean, scale=sd)

x1 = get_truncated_normal(mean=183, sd=50, low=1, upp=365).rvs(5722176)
x2 = get_truncated_normal(mean=175, sd=50, low=1, upp=365).rvs(5722176)
plt.hist(x1)
plt.hist(x2)
plt.show()
print(stats.ks_2samp(x1, x2))

Output:
Ks_2sampResult(statistic=0.06409554686888352, pvalue=0.0)
```

Why my output `p-value` is always `0.0`?Any help is truly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this stats stackoverflow post. 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18408/two-samples-of-the-same-distribution

which suggests Kolmogorov-Smirnov test.

And you can perform KS test using scipy.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kstest.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip. In my case, I believe its the `scipy.stats.ks_2samp`. However, when I use this, I always get p-value to be 0.0

Comment: You may be using the wrong returned value from the `ks_samp`. The first returned value is the KS test statistic, which is a measure of the distances between the cumulative distribution functions, so small means they are close together, and the second returned value is the p-value.

So your code would look something like `ksTestStatistic, pValue = scipy.stats.ks_2samp(x1, x2)`, and if I run this on your example, I get a KS test statistic of `0.0097` and a p-value of `0.73`, which is unable to reject the null hypothesis that they come from the same distribution (as expected).

Comment: @alexpiers, thanks! Yes, for the above example I get the KS statistic and p-value correct. I did test this approach on a different larger dataset (~ 5754105 data points in each array) that went through multiple masks (I made sure there are no nan or inf values),but the p-value always is 0.0. Any thoughts? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @pyPN, it is difficult to say without seeing the datasets you are comparing. What is the KS test statistic for this case?

Comment: @alexpiers..`Ks_2sampResult(statistic=0.0824579016707816, pvalue=0.0)`

Comment: @alexpiers, is `ks_2samp` sensitive to large sample size? I tested with different sample sizes and as sample size increases, the p-value decreases substantially.

Comment: Hi, so if I run on 10 million points sampled from a normal distribution, I get consistent results with the null hypothesis. ```import numpy as np
import scipy.stats

N = int(1e7)
x = np.random.uniform(0, 1, N)
y = np.random.uniform(0, 1, N)

print(scipy.stats.ks_2samp(x, y))``` Gives me `Ks_2sampResult(statistic=0.00046429999999997307, pvalue=0.23127393373572536)`. So again, without your data it is difficult to diagnose what is going wrong (if the two data sets do indeed come from the same distribution).

Comment: @alexpiers, thanks! The two data sets are independent and both of their distribution is more or less normal. The sample size is `5722176` and i tried creating two arrays with the sample size and i do get p-value. For e.g., `array1 = np.random.randint(1, 365, size=5722176)` and `array2 = np.random.randint(1, 365, size=5722176)`. `print(scipy.stats.ks_2samp(array1, array2)` yields `Ks_2sampResult(statistic=0.0007154620899462172, pvalue=0.10687372452805023)`

Comment: @alexpiers, I have edited my original code to reflect my actual case. Please take a look.